# Selecting TD with specific classes from each TR and do math

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a quite simple table. 
Each TR with class "name-check" will be looped in php for as long as there are $name. Each new TR is getting a new class name with a counter, so basically the structures of the TR in this table looks like this:
[Screenshot of table](http://prntscr.com/bt77if)

```
<tr class="name-check name_1">
<tr class="name-check name_2">
<tr class="name-check name_3">
etc.
```

This is the  content of each TR:

```
// Content of TR

<tr class="name-check name_1">
    <td class="name">
      <?php echo $name; ?>
    </td>

    <td class="check-date">
        <label class="check-label"></label>    
    </td>

    <td class="check-date">
        <label class="check-label"></label>     
    </td>

    <td class="check-date">
        <label class="check-label"></label>      
    </td>

    <td class="dont-count"></td>

    <td class="check-date">
        <label class="check-label"></label>       
    </td>


    <td class="sum-up" align="center">
        <span class="sum-up-span">0</span>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

This is the first TR which contains the TH:

```
// Table TH
<tr class="dates">
    <th></th>
    <th class="dat">1 </th>
    <th class="dat">2 </th>
    <th class="dat">3 </th>
    <th class="dat">4 </th>
    <th class="dont-count-th">Don't count</th> 
</tr>

// Table TH End and after this tr comes:
<tr class="name-check name_1">...
<tr class="name-check name_2">
<tr class="name-check name_3">
```

When a user clicks on a TD with the class "check-date" that TD will get an extra class. Actually it is a click loop:
- 1 time click adds class .one,
- 2 time click adds class .two,
- 3 time click adds class .three.

What I want basically is, for each row, get the TD's which have any of these three classes and substract them from the number of TD's with the class of "check-date", or I could use the "TH" with class ".dat". The result should be displayed in the last td of each tr, the span with class ".sum-up-span".

I got that working for a single row, but multiple rows, it gets all the values.

```
var totalDays = $("tr.dates th.dat").length;
var daysOff = $("tr.name-check").each(function() {
              $( "td.odsutan, td.godisnji, td.praznik" ).length;

var sum = totalDays - daysOff;

$(".sum-up-span").each(function () { 
    $(this).html("There " + sum + " from " + totalDays);
});
```

**SOLVED**
Both answers provided work great perfectly. Thank you guys for this.

Comment: What will happen in `fourth` click ?

Comment: @SherinJose it will remove those classes, meaning only the original class will stay. These extra classes only add background color to the td. They represent the "leave day" "holiday" and "sick day".

Comment: okay.. then the next click again starts from `one`, then `two` and `three`.. Right ?

Comment: @SherinJose no. The next click will remove all the extra classes so we are left with the default class of ".check-date".
".check-date will always remain, but we toggle 3 classes with 3 clicks, the forth click removes them.

Comment: Yeah.. posted an answer

Comment: @SherinJose Yes. It works. Both solutions work perfect. this is just so awesome

Comment: then why don't you mark a correct answer ? ;)

Comment: @SherinJose Both are working, I don't know which to pick

Comment: Then give upvote to both . No confusion. Otherwise next time when a user looks at this post he/she couldn't find which one is the good answer. :)

Comment: @SherinJose btw is there a way to save this to local storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one,

```
$("td.check-date").click(function(e) {
    if($(this).hasClass("one"))
        $(this).removeClass("one").addClass("two");
    else if($(this).hasClass("two"))
        $(this).removeClass("two").addClass("three");
    else if($(this).hasClass("three"))
        $(this).removeClass("three");
    else
        $(this).addClass("one");

    var tr                  = $(this).closest("tr");
    var td_count            = tr.find("td.check-date").length;
    var clicked_td_count    = tr.find("td.check-date.one, td.check-date.two, td.check-date.three").length;

    tr.find("span.sum-up-span").text(td_count - clicked_td_count);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery selectors are not limited to any container, so they search the entire page. What you need to do is limit them to the tr you clicked on.

Use the event `e` you get in a jQuery bound click function to do that:

```
function(e) {
  var currentRow = jQuery(e.currentTarget);

  var totalDays = $("tr.dates th.dat").length;
  var daysOff = $("td.odsutan, td.godisnji, td.praznik", currentRow).length;

  var sum = totalDays - daysOff;

  $(".sum-up-span", currentRow).html("There " + sum + " from " + totalDays);
}
```

Note: if you don't have jQuery bound click events and need help with that, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("table").on("click", "td.check-date", function() {
  var row = $(this).closest("tr"),
      checked = row.find(".one, .two, .three").length,  // get the number of clicked/checked columns
      toCheck = row.find(".check-date").length;  // get number of columns to check
    
  row.find(".sum-up-span").text(toCheck - checked);  // print missing checks in "sum-up" column
});


// this only adds the "click" feature for a better visibility :D
(function() {
  var classes = ["one", "two", "three", ""];
  $("td.check-date").on("click", function() {
    var td = $(this),
        clicked = td.data("clicked") || 0;

    td.data("clicked", clicked + 1);
    this.className = "check-date " + classes[clicked % classes.length];
  });
}())
```

```css
td {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 20px
}

.one { background-color: green }
.two { background-color: yellow }
.three { background-color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
     <tr class="name-check">
      <td class="name"></td>
      <td class="check-date"></td>
      <td class="check-date"></td>
      <td class="check-date"></td>
      <td class="dont-count"></td>
      <td class="check-date"></td>
      <td class="sum-up" align="center">
        <span class="sum-up-span">0</span>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="name-check">
      <td class="name"></td>
      <td class="check-date"></td>
      <td class="check-date"></td>
      <td class="check-date"></td>
      <td class="dont-count"></td>
      <td class="check-date"></td>
      <td class="sum-up" align="center">
        <span class="sum-up-span">0</span>
      </td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```